# automatically change php form row value by changing another row value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ticketing support system and I have some rows when in `call_edit.php` file. I have two rows called `staff` and `status`. When someone send us a ticket, the ticket status by default is `open` and the staff row is empty (`0` in my code). I want that when I change the staff value from empty (`0` in my code) to a name (`kitty`, `John` or something else), the status automatically changes from `open` to `Checking`.

**This is my php form**:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="width: 150px;">Status</td>
    <td>
        <select name='call_status'>
            <option value='0'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 0){echo ' selected';}?>>Open</option>
            <option value='2'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 2){echo ' selected';}?>>Checking</option>
            <option value='1'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 1){echo ' selected';}?>>Closed</option>
            <option value='3'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 3){echo ' selected';}?>>Deleted</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Staff</td>
    <td>
        <select name='call_staff'>
            <option value="0"></option>
        <?php $staff_name = $db->get_results("select user_id,user_name from site_users where user_level<>1 order by user_name;");
        foreach ($staff_name as $staff )
        {?>
            <option value='<?php echo $staff->user_id;?>'<?php if($staff->user_id == $call_staff){echo ' selected';}?>>
                <?php echo $staff->user_name;?>          
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it purely with php, you have to check the status of `$_POST['call_staff']`. If this is other than 0, set the call_status to 2.

```
if($_POST['call_staff'] != 0) {
    $callStatus = 2;
}
```

Then post that along to your sql query.